# one table with a lot of rows or a lot of tables with a view? on SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

My question comes from what is more efficient when making queries and insert, since the number of registers(data) in my table will grow a lot.

I would like to know what is more efficient to do if all the data is placed within a single table or is the partition and through a View and trigger is more efficient to obtain and enter registers(data).

Comment: Please provide sample data and a better explanation for what you are trying to do.  What "efficiency" are you concerned about?

Comment: look at this, may help https://www.studytonight.com/dbms/database-normalization.php

Comment: @GordonLinoff well i refer with efficient to get more speed to write and read data from DB with a lot of registers unique, i need to know how is better to save this data, it in single table o in a view with a lot of tables to partition in months (maybe) with the same columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already mentioned take a look at [database normalization](https://www.studytonight.com/dbms/database-normalization.php).

SQL is a way to work with relational databases and is built on the idea that we should have many tables that are linked with each other trough [relationships](https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/sql-for-beginners-part-3-database-relationships--net-8561). Thus I recommend multiple tables, because you will be able to reuse data (for example user name and surname) through specific IDs rather than copying that data each time a user performs some action on your platform and you need to insert or update some information.

Hope this helps!

Comment: TY for your answer but i refer to the quantity of registers in a table can stored with more efficient, not to th normalization where "less columns are better"